# Reduce motion blur for fast moving ball

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, camera, motion-blur

I am trying to create a simple ball tracking system. It does not have to be perfect as it is not for commercial/production.

On the hardware side I am using RaspberryPI with RPI camera V2. On the software - OpenCV.

If there is a natural sun light (even if there are some clouds) ball is totally visible. But when the sun is gone and there is only artificial lights there is a big motion blur visible on the ball.
On the picture below top object is ball with artificial light and bottom one is with natural light.

[image]

This is rather obvious - less light - longer exposure and with combination of rolling shutter we get motion blur.
I tried all the settings (like exposure sports/night mode) on this camera but I think it is just hardware limitations. I would like to improve this and reduce motion blur. I would need to get different camera that would handle this better but I have really poor knowledge about camera sensors, parameters etc. I cannot afford to buy many cameras, compare them and then select the best one. So my question is - **which camera model (compatible with RPI) should I pick or which parameters should I look for to get better results? (less motion blur)**

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: e.g. would global shutter reduce the problem? (cam like: ArduCam OV2311 2Mpx Global Shutter)

EDIT2: Maybe slower shutterspeed would change something but I also need good fps (20-30) does it "collide"?

EDIT3: [Here I read](https://community.mobotix.com/t/motion-blur-why-it-occurs-and-how-to-eliminate-it/114) that maybe using night (NoIR) camera would help since it is more light sensitive.

[image]

Regards

Comment: To decrease your exposure duration, you need more light, and/or more reflective subject, and/or higher ISO, and/or wider aperture, and/or to accept darker images.

Answer (score 2):

In order to reduce the motion blur, you have to use faster shutter speed namely reducing the exposure time, sometimes combined with extra illuminators.
For the Raspberry pi, you have to disable autoexposure and set it manually with shutter speed value.

Hint:

1. Global shutter camera doesn't help motion blur, it only helps with the rolling shutter artifacts. It still needs very fast shutter speed to avoid motion blur.
2. Fps doesn't have something to do with the shutter speed, it only is limited by the read out speed from the sensor.
3. NoIR might not help as well, because it still need the strong illumination for faster shutter speed.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. So as far I understand it I should be looking at:
1) fast shutter speed (is it combined with any camera's parameter?)
2) wide aperture
3) big light sensitivity (small Responsivity?)

Comment: 1. fast shutter speed: yes, it depends on which camera and camera driver you are using and set the camera parameter accordingly. 2. wide aperture: means a bigger lens. 3 big light sensitivity: means higher power illuminator