# how to reduce motion blur in picture?

Tags: opencv, qr-code, motion-blur

I am trying to detect the QR data from a blurry image and have not been successful till now.

[image: the picture]

I have tried a couple of morphology operations on the image and still did not get the data embedded in it.

How could I improve the situation?

I have tried this so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/barcode.hpp>

int main() {
  cv::Mat imageMat = cv::imread("/Users/apple/Downloads/36.jpg");
  if(imageMat.empty()) {
    std::cout << "Image not present and can not be opened" << std::endl;
    return 0;
  }

  cv::Mat     imageGray, imageBlur, imageCanny, imageDilated, imageEroded, thresholdImage;
  cv::cvtColor(imageMat, imageGray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
  cv::GaussianBlur(imageGray, imageBlur, cv::Size(3,3), 3, 0);
  std::cout << "Gaussian blur done" << std::endl;
  // cv::Canny(imageBlur, imageCanny, 25, 75);
  cv::Mat kernel = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(3,3));
  cv::dilate(imageBlur, imageDilated, kernel);
  cv::erode(imageDilated, imageEroded, kernel);
  cv::threshold(imageEroded, thresholdImage, 5, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY+cv::THRESH_OTSU);
  std::cout << "Threshold done" << std::endl;

  // Reads the barcode/dat
  cv::QRCodeDetector qrDecoder;
  std::string decodedData = qrDecoder.detectAndDecode(thresholdImage);
  std::cout << "Decoded data =  " << decodedData << std::endl;
```

This code is not decoding the data from the image which has blurry QR code. What would you guys prefer to unblur the image and get the data embedded in it? Increase the contrast? Increase the brightness?
Any document can be helpful too.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please define "This code is not working".

Comment: @kebs. :) Sure.

Comment: I's suggest to save to disk the images at each step, so you can see the quality of the image you feed into the qr code detector. If it fails, probably quality isnt good enough.

Comment: Hey @kebs, thanks for your reply again. I have uploaded the data, pic attached. This is the original image btw. Yes, this is what I did earlier during my day that seeing the quality of the image and it did not look good. That is why it fails.

Comment: Again, if it fails, it is because you do not provide a decent image. So you need to work out a sequence of operations that enhances the image, no magic trick. Maybe build a GUI with some sliders to adjust of your parameters, display in/out image at each line, and tweak the parameters until you get it right. Would be hard to give a better advice...

Comment: use more light, which causes shorter exposure times. related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/how-to-unblur-the-image/5510

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reduce motion blur for fast moving ball](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63615441/reduce-motion-blur-for-fast-moving-ball)

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, Thanks a lot for trying out. It gave me only a hint about the answer actually that I might need to get a camera that avoids motion blur. I was looking for something software specific actually.

Comment: a *very carefully* chosen threshold *might* make this picture readable.